# Read first line of file with Files.lines in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I want to use this code to read only the first line from a file:

```
String line = Files.lines(path).findFirst().get();
```

I assume that this does NOT load the contents of the entire file into memory. Instead, it opens the file, reads ONLY the first line and then closes the file.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Added File-IO tag to make tags more specific

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Files#lines` method uses a `BufferedReader` class to access the lines using `BufferedReader#lines`. From the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.lines%28%29)

> Returns a Stream, the elements of which are lines read from this
>   BufferedReader. The java.util.stream.Stream is lazily populated, i.e.,
>   read only occurs during the terminal stream operation. The reader must
>   not be operated on during the execution of the terminal stream
>   operation. Otherwise, the result of the terminal stream operation is
>   undefined.
>
> After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no
>   guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which
>   to read the next character or line.
>
> If an IOException is thrown when accessing the underlying
>   BufferedReader, it is wrapped in an UncheckedIOException which will be
>   thrown from the Stream method that caused the read to take place. This
>   method will return a Stream if invoked on a BufferedReader that is
>   closed. Any operation on that stream that requires reading from the
>   BufferedReader after it is closed, will cause an UncheckedIOException
>   to be thrown.

```
public Stream<String> lines() {
    Iterator<String> iter = new Iterator<String>() {
        String nextLine = null;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (nextLine != null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                try {
                    nextLine = readLine();
                    return (nextLine != null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            if (nextLine != null || hasNext()) {
                String line = nextLine;
                nextLine = null;
                return line;
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
            iter, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL), false);
}
```

The `Stream` created by `StreamSupport.stream` is backed by an `Iterator`. The stream is only asked for one element because you call `Stream#findFirst`. Therefore only one call to `hasNext` and `next` are made, meaning that `BufferedReader#readLine` is only called once.

Comment: So if it's a BufferedReader, then it will only read what's necessary, which in my case would be one line, and then close the reader, right? (Of course, if I continue to consume the stream, then it would read the rest).

Comment: @stepanian exactly! `lazily populated` is the key here

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict @Matt. Who should I believe? lol

Comment: There's a difference between having the ability to read when necessary in the stream (what I called reading) and storing in memory. Both are correct, but select this one as correct, since it explains the lazy memory concept.

Comment: @stepanian we don't contradict! Matt states that you **can** load all memory. I'll post more code to highlight

Comment: @flakes Matt changed his answer almost completely :)

Comment: @stepanian I should have paid more attention to the potential to load in memory vs. actual loading in memory, sorry.

Comment: @MattGoodrich No problem my friend. So the bottom line is my initial assumption in my question is correct, right?

Comment: @stepanian Correct

Answer (score 7):

From the [Files Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

> static Stream lines(Path path) - Read all lines from a file as a
>   Stream.

`Files.lines(path)` reads all lines, meaning they have the potential to be accessed, but **what's loaded into memory depends on what's required for the stream**. In your case, only the first line will be accessed (stored in memory), since the `BufferedReader` is able to lazily load contents into memory as necessary.